# How to delete an app's data when app is deleted

Tags: android

I want to delete an Android app and it's associated data. I have deleted the app and set the property 
`android:allowBackup="false"`. How can I delete the previous app data?

Comment: Android will handle that for you.

Comment: So to delete an app data go to file manager- internal memory- Android-data- then you can delete your desired app data

Comment: I have searched extensively in internal memory of the device for deleting the folder, but found none. However on reinstalling the app, the past data was still there.

Answer (score 0):

database of the app and shared preferences data will be automatically deleted by the Android iOS once you uninstall the app.

in case you had `android:allowBackup = "true"` 
follow this from [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup)

> Users can see a list of apps that have been backed up in the Google Drive Android app. On an Android-powered device, users can find this list in the Drive app's navigation drawer under Settings > Backup and reset > App data.

Comment: The later builds of the app still has the past data. This is when backup is disabled and there is no trace of the file in local storage. I have also cleared the cache after uninstall. However on reinstalling the app from a new build, I am still seeing the old data that was supposed to be deleted.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by data?

Comment: My app had past machine learning models that I want to delete before installing the app from a new build. Any suggessions on how I can do that

Comment: if you know where the files are stored you can just delete them. if you don't you can try this: run the app on your device/emulator. from Device File explorer find the package name to your app then delete all the files and reinstall.

Comment: Could you tell how I can find these files as they are not present in the Android folder of the device

Comment: you can press double shift and write "device file explorer" press enter when it appears